# Cocos2D Sprite Animation Batch Node Troubles

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

I get the following error: `'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'`

This is what I'm doing:

```
.h file

@interface GameplayLayer : CCLayer <GameplayLayerDelegate> { 
    CCSpriteBatchNode* pointbb;
}



.m file

pointbb = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"pointsbb.png"];

[self addChild:pointbb];

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"pointsbb.plist"];

CCSprite* spa = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"poi2500001.png"];

[pointbb addChild:spa];
```

The exact syntax worked for other animations but this one. What should be my correct course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding a `CCSprite` as a child of `CCBatchNode`.. use textures from batchnode..

Use this method..

```
[CCSprite spriteWithBatchNode: rect:]
```

In case you add your sprite to layer like `[self addChild:]` .. Your code will perfectly..

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: As stated, other animations work using the same syntax. I don't want to try your method.